# Angular save file as csv result in Failed- network error Only on Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, csv

I'm using the following code to save file as csv.

```
$scope.saveCSVFile = function (result)
{
    var a         = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(result.data);
    a.target      = '_blank';
    a.download    =  $scope.getFileNameFromHttpResponse(result);
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    $scope.isReportInProgress = false;
};
```

The file is working on most of the cases but for some reason when the file is larger than 10MB i get "Failed - Network Error".

It happens only on chrome.

I tried to search the web for this issue and couldn't find anything relevant.

Can you think of an idea why does it happens? or maybe use a different save file method that will work on chrome/firefox/IE instead of my function?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I was finally used this one, hope it can help the next one encounter this issue:

```
 var blob = new Blob([result.data], {type: 'text/csv'});
            var filename =  $scope.getFileNameFromHttpResponse(result);
            if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
            }
            else{
                var elem = window.document.createElement('a');
                elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                elem.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(elem);
                elem.click();
                document.body.removeChild(elem);
            }
```

Comment: [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) is otherwise a good alternative to saving blobs client side. It takes care of browser difference

Comment: This saved me! I was suspicious that I needed to use the blob API but wasn't sure the error was related. Thanks a lot

Comment: Worked very well, tyvm

Comment: Saved my day!  Thanks ;-)

Comment: Don't forget to URL.revokeObjectURL() or the blob will not be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but had to serve a zip file, sent from the server in base64 format. What did the trick for me:

```
function downloadBlob(data, filename) {
    const blob = new Blob([new Buffer(data, 'base64')], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});

    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
        const elem = window.document.createElement('a');
        elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        elem.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
        elem.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(elem.href);
        document.body.removeChild(elem);
    }        
}

return (
  {/* ... */}
  <a href="#" onClick={() => {downloadBlob(report.zip, `${report.filename}.zip`)}}>
      Download <b>{report.filename}.zip</b>
  </a>
  {/* ... */}
);
```

I left the function because like the fact that it revokes the URL after serving the file.